# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty in Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am loading image from mysql DB using Picasso into custom listview. The image is loading when the URL is passed directly but when i assign the URL to string and pass it then it throws exception saying Path must not be empty.

```
String imageStringUrl = md.Image;
```

Image string contains http://example.com/image.jpg

I am passing in Picasso like below.

```
Picasso.get()
.load(imageStringUrl)
.into(iview);
```

When I pass like this I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty. I have tried the above step like below but the image is not loading.

```
Picasso.get()
.load(new File(imageStringUrl))
.into(iview);
```

What is wrong with the above declaration?

Comment: According to error `Image` is blank not null. Are you sure this has a url?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I feel none of the answers below are giving the right answer

Comment: Don't try to open the link. It's NSFW.

Answer (score 46):

I had a similar problem. Just check if your URL string is empty or not. if it is empty give the default image or load from URL. Hope this helps.

```
if (image.isEmpty()) {
   iview.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
} else{
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(iview);
  }
```

Comment: this is the best way to make another no pic if the data not loaded, thank you so much

Comment: Check my answer, with this if statement you can still get exception.

Answer (score 4):

Just check if your url string is empty or not by first trimming the string path, but do not check like `image.isEmpty()` but with this check:

```
if (path.trim().length() == 0)
```

I checked the code from Picasso and that is how they are checking like this. For reference here is code from their code base:

```
public RequestCreator load(String path) {
    if (path == null) {
      return new RequestCreator(this, null, 0);
    }
    if (path.trim().length() == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path must not be empty.");
    }
    return load(Uri.parse(path));
  }
```

Comment: Strings.isEmpty works like this : "public inline fun CharSequence.isEmpty(): Boolean = length == 0".

So, I don’t think that « trim » or not is relevant

Answer (score 0):

I think your `md.Image`is returning an empty string. So try directly put your `image url` in `picasso` like this:

```
Picasso.get()
.load(" http://xxx.xxx.com/images/New%20folder/Desert.jpg.")
.into(imageView);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: this kind of solution is not usfull, we don't always know the link, sometimes the link is inside a variable so please try to give a better detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I realized that I had made a simple mistake.

In my code, I save the image URL in a snippet, and then retrieve the image URL, but at that point I was not calling the var that stores the data ...

```
imagemRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
    Uri url = task.getResult();
    
   urlImagemSelecionada = url.toString(); // This line I have forgot
   }
});
```

So the message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty in Picasso` was presented. Because the parameter was really empty.

Something simple, that made me lose 1 hour. But luckily it has now been resolved.