# The app crashes on using picasso and sending an empty picture

Tags: android, picasso

I am using picasso for my navigation drawer profile picture.

The app crashes as soon as I click on the display picture in the navigation drawer.
However, it is works fine when a picture is uploaded here beforehand and on clicking it shows the complete User Profile, which comes from the back-end.

My code is :

```
public class ProfileActivity extends BaseActivity {

@InjectView(R.id.svParent)
ScrollView svParent;

@InjectView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar mToolbar;

@InjectView(R.id.action_title)
TextView tvActionTitle;

@InjectView(R.id.civProfileImage)
CircleImageView civProfileImage;

@InjectView(R.id.tvName)
TextView tvName;

@InjectView(R.id.tvCity)
TextView tvCity;

@InjectView(R.id.etEmail)
EditText etEmail;

@InjectView(R.id.etPhoneNumber)
EditText etPhoneNumber;

@InjectView(R.id.etAlternatePhoneNumber)
EditText etAlternatePhoneNumber;

@InjectView(R.id.etAddress)
EditText etAddress;

@InjectView(R.id.etDescription)
EditText etDescription;

@InjectView(R.id.llProgressContainer)
LinearLayout llProgressContainer;

public static Intent callingIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    setParentView(svParent);
    setActionBar();
    initUserProfile();
}

private void setActionBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        supportActionBar.setTitle("");
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    tvActionTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_user_profile));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void initUserProfile() {
    String prefsData = SharedPrefsManager.getUserData(getApplicationContext());
    UserData userData = new Gson().fromJson(prefsData, UserData.class);
    Data data = userData.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        String name = data.getName();
        String city = data.getCity();
        String mobile = data.getMobile();
        String alternateMobile = data.getAlternateMobile();
        String mail = data.getEmail();
        String address = data.getAddress();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            tvName.setText(name);
        } else {
            tvName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(city)) {
            tvCity.setText(city);
        } else {
            tvCity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile)) {
            etPhoneNumber.setText(mobile);
            etPhoneNumber.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            etPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(alternateMobile)) {
            etAlternatePhoneNumber.setText(alternateMobile);
            etAlternatePhoneNumber.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            etAlternatePhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mail)) {
            etEmail.setText(mail);
            etEmail.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            etEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
            etAddress.setText(address);
            etAddress.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            etAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl()) ? APIMethods.LIVE_SERVER + data.getImageUrl() : "")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .into(civProfileImage);
    }
}
```

}

The exceptions which pop up are:

```
07-18 08:40:31.268 8668-8668/in.mahabir E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                      Process: in.mahabir, PID: 8668
                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.mahabir/in.mahabir.ui.profile.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
                                                          at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:194)
                                                          at in.mahabir.ui.profile.ProfileActivity.initUserProfile(ProfileActivity.java:154)
                                                          at in.mahabir.ui.profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:78)
                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

which is basically an IllegalArgumentException : Path cannot be left blank.

I read in a few places that Picasso cant handle null addresses. Can someone please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl())){// load image } else {civProfileImage.setimageResource(R.drawable.ic_user);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Older Versions of Picasso:**

Try this

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl()) ? APIMethods.LIVE_SERVER + data.getImageUrl() : R.drawable.ic_user)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .into(civProfileImage);
```

Or this

```
try{
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(APIMethods.LIVE_SERVER + data.getImageUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .into(civProfileImage);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .into(civProfileImage);
}
```

**For New Version of Picasso:**

Try this

```
Picasso.get()
        .load(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl()) ? APIMethods.LIVE_SERVER + data.getImageUrl() : R.drawable.ic_user)
         .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
         .into(civProfileImage);
```

Or this

```
try{
    Picasso.get()
            .load(APIMethods.LIVE_SERVER + data.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
            .into(civProfileImage);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Picasso.get()
           .load(R.drawable.ic_user)
           .into(civProfileImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl())) {
       Picasso.get()
            .load(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl()) ? APIMethods.LIVE_SERVER + data.getImageUrl() : "")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
            .into(civProfileImage);
    } else {
    civProfileImage.setimageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getImageUrl())) {
                        Picasso.with(data.getImageUrl())
                                .load(R.drawable.ic_user)
                                .into(civProfileImage);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso does not allow you to set empty path. From your Logcat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty
```

check the Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721692/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-path-must-not-be-empty-in-picasso)

Answer (score 0):

Adding others answers, Picasso allows you to manage downloads errors with

```
Picasso.error(DEFAULT IMAGE);
```