# Having errors after Cleaning project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The logcat has the following error occurred after cleaning the project.The project was running fine before that no errors like that were noticed before.I need help to solve this issue.Below is the logcat error. The code is in Kotlin Language and it appears that error is in onBindViewHolder.

```
08-02 12:52:41.370 16984-16984/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
08-02 12:53:10.883 16984-16984/com.malik_tayyab.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.malik_tayyab.testapp, PID: 16984
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
        at com.maliktayyab.testapp.Newsfeedholder.bind(Newsfeedholder.kt:15)
        at com.maliktayyab.testapp.FragmentNewsfeed.onBindViewHolder(FragmentNewsfeed.kt:48)
        at com.maliktayyab.testapp.FragmentNewsfeed.onBindViewHolder(FragmentNewsfeed.kt:21)
        at com.mobymagic.easyfirebaselist.database.FirebaseDbAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseDbAdapter.kt:22)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:118)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1767)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at an
```

My Newsfeed Holder class which is in logcat.

```
class Newsfeedholder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(model : News)}
   itemView.NewsTitleTextView.text = model.title
        Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(model.thumbnail).into(itemView.NewsThumbnailImageView)
    }
}
```

My FragmentNewsfeed firebasefragment class.

```
class FragmentNewsfeed : FirebaseDbListFragment<News,Newsfeedholder>() {
        override fun getDataClass(): Class<News> {
                return News::class.java

        }

    override fun getEmptyStyle(): EmptyStyle {
                return EmptyStyle(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "No News in database yet")

        }

        override fun getErrorStyle(error: DatabaseError): ErrorStyle {
                return ErrorStyle(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "An Error occurred while fetching news")

        }

        override fun getProgressStyle(): ProgressStyle {
                return ProgressStyle(progressMessage = "Loading....")

        }

        override fun getQuery(): Query {
                return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("newsfeed").limitToLast(100)

        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: Newsfeedholder, key: String, model: News) {
                viewHolder.bind(model = model)

        }
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, viewGroup: ViewGroup): Newsfeedholder {
                val new = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_fragment, viewGroup, false)
                return Newsfeedholder(new)
        }


        override fun onItemClicked(viewHolder: Newsfeedholder, key: String, model: News) {
        FinestWebView.Builder(activity).show(model.link)

        }

        override fun setupRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        }


    }
```

Comment: try once Invalidate cache/ Restart android studio, presents in file option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `model.thumbnail` is returning empty. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721692/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-path-must-not-be-empty-in-picasso), it may help you.

Comment: You can do it. Just create an if else statement that if `model.thumbnail.isEmpty()`, then set a default image from your drawable. Else, use the Picasso.load().

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.

You can see this error. Your path is empty, you need non empty path: `model.thumbnail` is an empty string. Picasso loads non empty path.
        `Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(model.thumbnail).into(itemView.NewsThumbnailImageView)`

Comment: But the link is all set and why did this occur after working for at least a month

Comment: I think you can show log or debug. I can sure this path is empty. Or  can check this link is empty, you show another default image.